# Maintaining LAN Redundancy in c++

Tags: c++, udp

I'm using Dell precision 3930 Rack workstation. It has two 10G LAN sockets to receive/send UDP data from other sub-systems.

Our C++ application spawns 2 threads. One thread receives/sends data from LAN1 and the other thread uses LAN2 for receive/send data. Both the threads are running independent.

Requirement:

By default Thread1 should receive data from LAN1 and Thread2 should not be doing any work.

Thread2 uses LAN2 to start receiving data when LAN1 is not present (LAN1 cable removed or some other hardware failure)

Thread2 will continue receiving data. LAN1 cable is connected and LAN2 cable is removed.

Now Thread2 goes to sleep and thread1 starts receiving data.

LAN2 cable connected. Thread2 sleeps still.

Summary:

LAN1 - connected, LAN2 - connected  ---------------  Thread1 receives and process data, Thread2 sleeps.

LAN1 - already connected, LAN2 - removed    ---------------  Thread1 continues to receive and process data, Thread2 sleeps.

LAN1 -   removed, LAN2 - connected  ---------------  Thread2 receives and process data, Thread1 sleeps.

LAN1 -   connected, LAN2 - already connected  ---------------  Thread2 continues to receive and process data, Thread1 sleeps.

LAN1 - removed, LAN2 - removed --------------- Thread1 and Thread2 goes to sleep.

Please someone suggest to me how to achieve this in c++?

Comment: So there are three threads - main thread, thread 1 and thread 2. Use main thread to continuously check availability of LAN1 and LAN2 and then you can use condition variables to trigger wait (sleep) and notify.

Comment: The problem you have is that the only standard C++ network library is Berkeley Sockets. BS does not support threading, they are simply too old. The C++ replacement (Network TS) has been repeatedly kicked into the long-grass. Your problem does not require threads, as network IO is by nature asynchronous, and using an asynchronous (non-blocking) model, this problem is a lot easier. I can provide an answer if you define if you prefer Boost/ASIO (almost Network TS, native C++) or prefer a C-style OS solution (in which case you will need to tell me which OS you are on).

Comment: I prefer a C-style OS solution for RHEL8.0